# Android CameraX seems to crop analysis images slightly for specific PreviewView sizes

Tags: android, camera, aspect-ratio, android-camerax

Dependencies used:

```
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha24'
```

Pretend that for simplicity you're using a device with:

- a portrait default orientation
- 1080x1920 screen resolution
- with `ImageAnalysis` configured to use 1080x1920 as frames analysis resolution

When a `PreviewView` is laid out with sizes close to 1080x1920
and `FILL_CENTER` as a scale type,
we're getting analysis frames with the same contents as we see in the `PreviewView` - it's ok.
When our `PreviewView` becomes a little bit more narrow,
for example 700x1920 - it gets cropped parts of analysis frames:
some parts of the frames on the left and right now look cropped - it's ok too.

But when we change the sizes of the `PreviewView` to make it look as landscape,
for example - to 1080x500 there is an issue appears.
Our `PreviewView` makes the frames from the camera look cropped
from top and bottom - it's ok.
But what's not ok - is that our analysis frames become **actually** cropped **veeery slightly**
at left and right.
That means I expect to see the same capture bounds horizontally both in `PreviewView` and frames
(because due to scaling only vertical parts are cropped),
but `PreviewView` actually shows a little bit more along its width
rather than the corresponding frame, so it looks like the frame looses about 20px horizontally,
what shouldn't occur, because due to frame (1080x1920) and `PreviewView` (1080x500) sizes,
only vertical parts should be clipped.

Attaching an illustration:
[image]

Do anyone encounter the same behaviour in the CameraX?

UPD: How did I find this out? - By saving frames (images) to files.
Frame buffers are converted to `cv::Mat`s with:

```
void nv21_buffer_to_bgr_mat(JNIEnv* env,
                            jbyteArray nv21_buffer,
                            jint width,
                            jint height,
                            cv::Mat& mat)
{

    // To YUV.
    jbyte* nv21_buffer_bytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(nv21_buffer, nullptr);
    cv::Mat yuv(height + height / 2, width, CV_8UC1, nv21_buffer_bytes);

    // To BGR.
    cvtColor(yuv, mat, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21, 3);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(nv21_buffer, nv21_buffer_bytes, 0);

}
```

UPD2: Maybe layout inspector images for the described above cases will be helpful:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying camera2 API has a fairly strictly defined set of rules on how having multiple output resolutions works, in terms of cropping.
The docs for the SCALER_CROP_REGION (digital zoom) control have [useful diagrams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#SCALER_CROP_REGION) about this; for your case, just assume the CROP_REGION covers the whole active array.

On top of that, CameraX PreviewView applies further cropping to its input, since the camera device itself only supports a few sizes.  So PreviewView will pick a supported resolution that has a reasonable aspect ratio, and then crop it if necessary when displaying it to fill your View layout area.

So, the relationship between the ImageAnalysis and Preview use cases and their fields of view depends on both the resolutions CameraX selects for the use cases under the hood, and PreviewView's additional cropping.

What's probably happening here is that your landscape PreviewView is selecting an underlying resolution that's wider than ImageAnalysis is selecting. You could check what's actually selected via `adb shell dumpsys media.camera` if you have developer access to a device, while your app is running.  That command dumps out a lot of info, including exactly what CameraX has configured the camera device to do.

You could try using the [setTargetAspectRatio](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/camera/core/Preview.Builder#settargetaspectratio) or the [setTargetResolution](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/camera/core/Preview.Builder#settargetresolution) methods on Preview.Builder to match the aspect ratio of the ImageAnalysis; that should ensure that the PreviewView is only ever a crop of what ImageAnalysis receives.

Comment: Eddy, the recommendation to use `setTargetResolution` on `Preview.Builder` helped me - no weird crops appear in my frames anymore ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ